# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals'

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error
*ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals'*

even though I have installed the package ´web-vitals'.` as it is shown in the package.json

```
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

I have restarted the IDE afterwards, however I still got the same error.
Any idea how could this being fixed?
thank you.

Comment: How does your import statement looks like ?

Comment: Hi Sushanth, this is what I have:  import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
//import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

Comment: Does `reportWebVitals.js` file exists?

Comment: try to install it in dependencies not in devDependencies this might help you

Comment: also import statement must be  import reportWebVitals from 'reportWebVitals'; not  import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; because you're calling a library not a file